# Problema con consulta SQL en PHP

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy tratando de ejecutar este codigo en `PHP` pero el resultado del `var_dump` siempre es **empty**

```
require("conexion.php");
$fecha = isset($_POST['fecha']) ? $_POST['fecha'] : NULL;

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
        G300.G300CTA    AS CUENTA,
        G300.G300NCTL   AS NOMBRE,
        G305.G305S01    AS SALDO_FINAL,
        G305.G305FDIA   AS FECHA

        FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300
        INNER JOIN BI_SRC.CCLF002 C002 ON G300.G300CLI = C002.C001CLI
        INNER JOIN BI_SRC.GTGF006 G006 ON G006.G005TDOC = C002.C002TDOC AND (G006.G005TDOC = 1 OR G006.G005TDOC = 2 OR G006.G005TDOC  = 6 OR G006.G005TDOC  = 8)
        INNER JOIN BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 ON G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
        INNER JOIN BI_SRC.VCVF002 V002 ON G300.G300UUID = V002.V001UUID AND TRUNC(V002.V002FAPE) <= ? AND (TRUNC(V002.V002FCIE) >= TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY/MM/DD')-1 OR (V002.V002FCIE IS NULL))

        WHERE

        G300.G300TCTA  = 'V'
        AND TRUNC(G305.G305FDIA) BETWEEN TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY/MM/DD')-1 AND ?
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BI_SRC.MRCJ000 M000 WHERE G300.G300CTA =  M000.G300CTA)
        AND G300.G300CTA = 8014003407
        ORDER BY G305.G305S01 DESC";

        $stid = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stid->bindParam(1, $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
        $stid->execute();
        $resultado = $stid->fetchAll();
        var_dump($resultado);
```

Cuando ejecuto el mismo codigo en `Oracle` me trae los resultados que necesito.

**Codigo en Oracle:**

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    G300.G300CTA    AS CUENTA,
    G300.G300NCTL   AS NOMBRE,
    G305.G305S01    AS SALDO_FINAL,
    G305.G305FDIA   AS FECHA

FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.CCLF002 C002 ON G300.G300CLI = C002.C001CLI
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.GTGF006 G006 ON G006.G005TDOC = C002.C002TDOC AND (G006.G005TDOC = 1 OR G006.G005TDOC = 2 OR G006.G005TDOC  = 6 OR G006.G005TDOC  = 8)
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 ON G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
INNER JOIN BI_SRC.VCVF002 V002 ON G300.G300UUID = V002.V001UUID AND TRUNC(V002.V002FAPE) <= '2019/02/15' AND (TRUNC(V002.V002FCIE) >= TO_DATE('2019/02/15', 'YYYY/MM/DD')-1 OR (V002.V002FCIE IS NULL))

WHERE

G300.G300TCTA  = 'V'
AND TRUNC(G305.G305FDIA) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019/02/15', 'YYYY/MM/DD')-1 AND '2019-02-15'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BI_SRC.MRCJ000 M000 WHERE G300.G300CTA =  M000.G300CTA)
AND G300.G300CTA = 8014003407
ORDER BY G305.G305S01 DESC;
```

No tengo problema con la conexion a la base de datos, ejecuto otro query y me trae resultados, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL
```

Codigo de `Conexion.php`:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=192.168.1.95:1521/orcl;charset=UTF8', 'bi_src', 'bi_src');
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

No se porque en `PHP` me devuelve **empty** y en  `Oracle` si me trae los datos.

Comment: Intentaste convertir la otra fecha que tienes en el where?

Comment: Te devuelve vacío  porque no es la misma query que en oracle. EN `BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019/02/15', 'YYYY/MM/DD')-1 AND '2019-02-15'` Si te fijas la primera fecha va con `/` y la segunda con `-`. Cuando la pasas en PHP solo va a llevar uno de los 2 formatos.

Comment: @JDev si, pero no importa si lo pasas con `-` o `/` oracle igual lo admite. En php, lo pasa con `-`.

Comment: Haz un echo de `$stid->error` para ver que devuelve. Y por lo que veo tienes numerosas `?` y solo haces un bind param, es posible que esos campos queden vacios afectando a tu query.

Comment: @MikelFerreiro Tambien pense lo de las numerosas `?` pero al colocar el mismo codigo de `oracle` en php, sin `?`, me devuelve **empty** tambien

Comment: Entonces tiene toda la pinta de que es algo de conexión o alguna excepción. Prueba a hacer un echo de `$stid->error`, rodear el codigo con un `try{}catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }`, y a verificar que la conexión esta bien;`if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}`

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras si, pero sucede lo mismo, en `oracle` funciona correctamente y en `php` devuelve vacio

Comment: Ok, según yo, no está creando correctamente la sentencia sql, por eso envía resultados en blanco. Lo que yo hago cuando tengo problemas como este es lanzar un mensaje con la cadena resultante, y ver qué es lo que está saliendo mal. La diferencia es que yo programo en C#, no se cómo podrías hacerlo en php.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que solo ocupas el parámetro `$fecha`:
Utiliza la sentencia preparada con parámetros de sustitución con nombre:
En lugar de ?, utiliza :fecha así como el ejemplo:

```
<?php
require("conexion.php");
$fecha = isset($_POST['fecha']) ? $_POST['fecha'] : NULL;

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
        G300.G300CTA    AS CUENTA,
        G300.G300NCTL   AS NOMBRE,
        G305.G305S01    AS SALDO_FINAL,
        G305.G305FDIA   AS FECHA

        FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300
        INNER JOIN BI_SRC.CCLF002 C002 ON G300.G300CLI = C002.C001CLI
        INNER JOIN BI_SRC.GTGF006 G006 ON G006.G005TDOC = C002.C002TDOC AND (G006.G005TDOC = 1 OR G006.G005TDOC = 2 OR G006.G005TDOC  = 6 OR G006.G005TDOC  = 8)
        INNER JOIN BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 ON G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
        INNER JOIN BI_SRC.VCVF002 V002 ON G300.G300UUID = V002.V001UUID AND TRUNC(V002.V002FAPE) <= :fecha AND (TRUNC(V002.V002FCIE) >= TO_DATE(:fecha, 'YYYY/MM/DD')-1 OR (V002.V002FCIE IS NULL))

        WHERE

        G300.G300TCTA  = 'V'
        AND TRUNC(G305.G305FDIA) BETWEEN TO_DATE(:fecha, 'YYYY/MM/DD')-1 AND :fecha
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BI_SRC.MRCJ000 M000 WHERE G300.G300CTA =  M000.G300CTA)
        AND G300.G300CTA = 8014003407
        ORDER BY G305.G305S01 DESC";

        $stid = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stid->bindParam(':fecha', $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
        $stid->execute();
        $resultado = $stid->fetchAll();
        var_dump($resultado);
```